# Calling a celery task from another celery task

Tags: django, celery

I have a celery task called `send_async_fax` and another called `send_notifications`. `send_async_fax` can be called directly. If you call `send_notifications`, however, `send_async_fax` will also be called.

`send_async_fax` has a number of arguments one of which is a list of `file` objects. If I call `send_async_fax` directly, everything seems to go as planned. However, when it's called indirectly, via `send_notifications`, I find that the list of valid open files degrades to a list of uninitialized files.

My hunch was that `send_notifications` was, in fact, creating separate asynchronous tasks for sending faxes when `send_async_fax.delay` was called (which, of course, makes sense). By doing this, however, I suspect that the file references are getting messed up, or that `send_notifications` is closing the files before `send_async_fax` actually gets to operate on them.

To test this hunch, I tried calling `send_async_fax` in `send_notifications` without using the `delay` function (i.e., send_async_fax(*args) instead of send_async_fax.delay(*args)). That didn't change anything. Then, I commented out the `task` decorator for `send_async_fax` to make it a regular function. In this case, everything works as expected.

So, to get this working, the obvious solution is to make a synchronous version of my faxing function and use it, instead of the async version, when calling from a celery task. I'm hoping, however, that there's a more elegant solution than this. Thanks for your help.

- celery==3.0.19
- django-celery==3.0.17

Answer (score 0):

I bet it has something to do with trying to serialize the open files as arguments for a delayed task.

Try sending fullpath filenames as input parameters to the send_async_fax function and opening the files in the send_async_fax.

I put an example here of one task calling another:

https://github.com/brentpayne/django-celery-example/blob/master/polls/tasks.py

https://github.com/brentpayne/django-celery-example/blob/master/polls/management/commands/one_task_calls_another.py

but you might want to do something more like:

```
group( send_async_fax.map(my_list_to_fax) ).delay()
```